# How to sum up how many elements of the same value for a specific field in a pandas dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe called hospitals and there are fields e.g number of employees and city that it is in.

I want to sum up how many hospitals are in each city and store that as a new column or field in the dataframe.

Tried this which doesn't work:

```
    print(df.groupby('city').agg({
    'city': pd.Series.nunique
}))

    hospital_id    name                    city
0             1    Cassel Hospital         London
1             2    Oaklands Hospital       Manchester
2             3    Bromley Hospital        London
```

I want it to be like this:

```
        hospital_id    name                    city    Count
0             1    Cassel Hospital         London       2
1             2    Oaklands Hospital       Manchester   1
2             3    Bromley Hospital        London       2
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the input data.

Comment: done, also this might work `print(df.groupby('city').size().reset_index(name='Count'))`, but I want the other fields to show also and every row not just each row with a unique city.

Comment: `df.groupby('city')['city'].transform('nunique')`